# Implement Availability test for Intranet application

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, appinsights, azure-monitor

I have an application which as intranet application. I have app insights configured on Azure. I want to configure the Availability test using URL ping method. Since my application is not on public internet, I am not able to implement the same. Please suggest the best approach to implement in this case.

Comment: App Insights isn't an Azure DevOps service. It's an Azure service.

Comment: I modified the question. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @user2327358 Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Comment: I am planning to have a worker service to implement a custom Availability test, as firewall option is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The URL configured in an availability test can be any web page you want to test, but it must be visible from the public internet.

If your URL is **not visible** from the public internet, you can choose to selectively open up your firewall to allow only the test transactions through. To learn more about the firewall exceptions for availability test agents, consult the [IP address guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses#availability-tests).

If direct inbound communication with the availability test agents in public Azure cannot be allowed, the only option would be to create and host your own [custom availability tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-azure-functions).

References:

- [Can I monitor an intranet web server?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#can-i-monitor-an-intranet-web-server)
- [Use availability tests on an internal server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/troubleshoot-availability#id-like-to-use-availability-tests-on-our-internal-server-that-runs-behind-a-firewall)